# Creating axis values that mix italic and normal font

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a plot where the axis values are category names where the name is italicized and it is followed by some text and a number inside parentheses. The category name and number are different for each axis value. For example, I would have "*Dog* (Pet 1)", "*Cat* (Pet 2)". I've looked over a number of other examples for doing this for the label of the axes, but not the labels parameter of `axis`. I'm a bit stuck...

```
par(mar=c(5,8,1,1))
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(1,5), ylab="", xlab="", axes=F)
axis(1)
pet <- c("Dog", "Cat", "Goldfish", "Dog", "Rabbit")
number <- 1:5
formatted <- paste("italic(", pet, ")~(Pet ", number, ")", sep="")
axis(2, labels=sapply(formatted, as.expression), at=1:5, las=2)
```

I hope I'm close, because the resulting plot has the `mathplot` syntax at the right positions (e.g. `italic(Dog)~(Pet 1)`), but it doesn't render correctly.

When I do it without the `sapply` call it complains that there's a mismatch between the number of labels and the at values.

When I do `axis(2, labels=parse(text=formatted), at=1:5, las=2)` then I get

```
Error in parse(text = formatted) : 
  <text>:1:18: unexpected numeric constant
1: italic(Dog)~(Pet 1
                     ^
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `formatted` to a list and use `bquote`. Then you can evaluate a list of expressions over a `do.call`.

```
par(mar=c(5,8,1,1))
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(1,5), ylab="", xlab="", axes=F)
axis(1)
pet <- c("Dog", "Cat", "Goldfish", "Dog", "Rabbit")
number <- 1:5
formatted <- lapply(1:5, function(i) bquote(paste(italic(.(pet[i]))~"(Pet", .(number[i]), ")", sep="")))
axis(2, labels=do.call(expression, formatted), at=1:5, las=2)
```

Another problem might have been that you don't need the quotes around the expression function calls (`italic`) within the paste.

Comment: no problem. You may have had better luck googling an answer by searching for "axis tick label".